# Define $f : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(A) = \langle A^2x,x \rangle.$ then ???

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space  of  all  $n\times n $ real matrices  identified  with  Euclidean space $\mathbb{R^{n^2}}$. Fixed a column vector   $x \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{ R^n}$. Define  $f : M_n(\mathbb{R})  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(A) = \langle A^2x,x \rangle$

Which of the following statements is True

1) $f$ is linear

2) $f$ is differentiable

3) $f$ is continuous but not differentiable

4) $f$ is  unbounded.

My attempts: I take  $A = \lambda I $ now  $f(A) = \langle \lambda^2x,x \rangle = \langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle$

here $f$ is differentiable and also $f$ is unbounded

so option 2 and option 4 are true,

I'm confused about option 1

Any hints/solution will be appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why Down Votes ?? ....................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $f$ is not linear. For instance, $f(2\operatorname{Id})=4\|x\|^2$, whereas $2f(\operatorname{Id})=2\|x\|^2$. But $f$ is differentiable, since it is expressed as the composition of differentiable functions. And it is unbounded, since$$(\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}):f(\lambda\operatorname{Id})=\lambda^2\|x\|^2.$$