# A function on space of $n\times n$ real matrices in euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Tags: real-analysis

This question was asked in my analysis assignment and my answers are wrong. So, I am asking it here.

> Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of all $n\times n$ real matrices identified with the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. Fix a column vector $x\neq 0$ . Define $f:M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ by  $f(A)= (A^2 x ,x)$ . THen

A) $f$ is linear

B) $f$ is differentiable

C) $f$ is continuous but not differentiable

D) $f$ is unbounded

I marked A , C but answers are B,D so Can you please tell  how to prove B, D and disprove A,C.

I shall be really thankful for your help.

Waiting for your help!!

Comment: $f(2A) = 4 f(A)$ so $f$ is not linear !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define $f : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(A) = \langle A^2x,x \rangle.$ then ???](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826964/define-f-m-n-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-by-fa-langle-a2x-x-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the usual inner product.

A. If $f$ was linear, then as stated in the comments you should get $f(2A)=2f(A)$, but since theres a square on the 2 there you will get a coefficient mismatch.

B. You can open the inner product explicitly and you will see that you get a polynomial in the coefficients of $A$, of 2nd degree. Alternatively, you can claim both $A \mapsto A^2$ is differentiable and you compose it with a multiplication by vectors on the left and the right to get $x^\top A^2 x$ which are constants, so it's still differentiable

D. You can look at the sequence of matrices $(A_k = k I_n)_{k \in \mathbb N}$. You get that
$$f(A_k) = k^2 (I_nx,x)=k^2\| x\|^2$$
which tends to infinity as $k\rightarrow \infty$, so $f$ can't be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $a_{ij}$ for the elements of the matrix $A$ (its "coordinates" in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$), and similarly $x_i$ for the coordinates of the vector $x\in \mathbb R^n$, then you can write the explicit form of $f:\mathbb R^{n^2}\to \mathbb R$ as
$$f(a_{ij}) = \left\langle A^2x,x\right\rangle = \sum_{i,j,k}x_i a_{ij} a_{jk} x_k$$
which is a polynomial in the coordinates $a_{ij}$ with coefficients depending on the $x_i$. This is differentiable, which proves B and disproves C.

edit for comments:

In components, the inner product is
$$\langle v,w\rangle = \sum_k v_k w_k,$$
and matrix multiplication is described by
$$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik}b_{kj},$$
that is, the $(i,j)$th element of the matrix $AB$ is given by the above number. Similarly, matrices multiply with vectors to give a vector, whose $i$th component is
$$(Av)_i = \sum_k a_{ik}v_k.$$
Now put all this together!

Comment: How did you wrote 3rd line of the answer. Can you please give reasoning?

Comment: Can you please tell how did you wrote $<A^2 x ,x> =\sum_{I,j,k} x_i a_{ij} a_{jk} x_k$ ? Can you please elaborate?